# C Dynamic Array based on input from console

Tags: c, arrays, io, char

I am writing a program that stores input from the console. To simplify it lets say I need to output what was wrote to the console.

So I have something like this:

```
int main()
{
  char* input;
  printf("Please write a bunch of stuff"); // More or less.
  fgets() // Stores the input to the console in the input char*

  printf(input);
}
```

So that is it in more or less. Just trying to give you the general idea. So what if they input something the size of 999999999999. How can I assign a char* to be that size dynamically.

Comment: posting the actual code rather than code which won't work (there's no backing memory for input variable) would be a better idea...

Comment: Put in sane maxima for what you deal with and treat it as an error otherwise.

Comment: there are some limits, like on length that console actually accepts. just allocate the length of string and make sure that allocation didn't fail

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[8192];
    printf("Please type a bunch of stuff: ");
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), fp) != 0)
        printf("%s", input);
    return(0);
}
```

That allows for a rather large space.  You could check that you actually got a newline in the data.

If that's not sufficient, then investigate the POSIX 2008 function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html), available in Linux, which dynamically allocates memory as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example - you need to validate the input and make sure you don't overflow your buffer. In this example, I discard anything over the max length and instruct the user to try again. Another approach would be allocating a new (larger) buffer when that happened.

`fgets()` second argument is the maximum number of characters you will read from the input. I'm actually accounting for the `\n` in this example and getting rid of it, you may not want to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getInput(char *question, char *inputBuffer, int bufferLength)
{
    printf("%s  (Max %d characters)\n", question, bufferLength - 1);
    fgets(inputBuffer, bufferLength, stdin);

    if (inputBuffer[strlen(inputBuffer) -1] != '\n')
    {
        int dropped = 0;
        while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n')
                dropped++;

        if (dropped > 0) // if they input exactly (bufferLength - 1) characters, there's only the \n to chop off
        {
                printf("Woah there partner, your input was over the limit by %d characters, try again!\n", dropped );
                getInput(question, inputBuffer, bufferLength);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inputBuffer[strlen(inputBuffer) -1] = '\0';      
    }

}


int main()
{
    char inputBuffer[10];
    getInput("Go ahead and enter some stuff:", inputBuffer, 10);
    printf("Okay, I got: %s\n",inputBuffer);
    return(0);
}
```